# Adding a class to an array of divs after a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a memory game more like mahjong. I've already completed most of it.

But the problem I'm facing is after selecting two divs/cards if they do not match they are not flipping back.

I tried to do this with an if/else statement where the selected divs are stored in a variable (in array form). But the flipping is happening to their parent div. So I used `parent()` to go to the parent div and add "isFlipped" class if they do not match. But it isn't working. I also tried to use `map()` to the variable where the selected divs are stored. It isn't working either.
here's my code

```js
//shuffle position of cards

$.fn.shuffleChildren = function () {
  $.each(this.get(), function (index, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var $find = $el.children();

    $find.sort(function () {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });

    $el.empty();
    $find.appendTo($el);
  });
};

$(".parent1").shuffleChildren();
$(".parent2").shuffleChildren();

var counter = 3;
var attempt = document.getElementById("count");
attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";


var inner = $(".inner");

function hideCards() {
  inner.addClass("isFlipped");
  inner.click(function () {
    var elem = $(this); //returns inner div
    elem.toggleClass("isFlipped");
    var child = elem.find(".front").children(); //returns block class
    //var first = child.attr("data-type"); //returns data-type of the block class
    if (child.hasClass("matched")) {
      return;
    }

    child.toggleClass("selected");
    child.siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");

    var selected = $("[data-type].selected");
    if (selected.length === 2) {
      var type1 = selected.eq(0).data("type");
      var type2 = selected.eq(1).data("type");
      var isMatch = type1 === type2;
      if (isMatch) {
        selected.removeClass("selected").toggleClass("matched", isMatch, 2000);
        attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";
      }
      else {
        selected.removeClass("selected");
        var inr = selected.parent().parent();
        console.log(inr);
        inr.map(function(element) {
          $(element).addClass("isFlipped");
        });

        counter -= 1;
        if (counter == 0) {
          attempt.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!!";
        }
        else {
          attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

setTimeout(hideCards, 5000);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,400i,700");

.parent1,
.parent2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;  
  display: flex;
}

.parent1 div,
.parent2 div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.block1,
.block2 {
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
}

[data-type].selected,
[data-type].selected:hover {
  border: 3px solid white;
}

[data-type].matched {
  display: none;
}

[data-type]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

[data-type="c1"] {
  background-color: #F44336;
}

[data-type="c2"] {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

[data-type="c3"] {
  background-color: #8E24AA;
}

[data-type="c4"] {
  background-color: #5E35B1;
}

[data-type="c5"] {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}

[data-type="c6"] {
  background-color: #00796B;
}

[data-type="c7"] {
  background-color: #AFB42B;
}

[data-type="c8"] {
  background-color: #FF8F00;
}

.gameover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: coral;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.buttons {
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.gameover h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* FLIP CARD */

.flip {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* .flip:hover .inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
} */

.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background-color: pink;
}

.back {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.inner.isFlipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameover">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>GAME OVER!!</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="">Retry</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="parent1">
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c1">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c8">8</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c7">7</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c6">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c5">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c4">4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c3">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent2">
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c1">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c8">8</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c7">7</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c6">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c5">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c4">4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c3">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="count"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"But the flipping is happening to their parent div."_ Is that what you want or not? In other words, do you want to apply the `isFlipped` class to the parent, or to the card within the parent?

Comment: @kmoser what i meant is the flipping side is controlled by their parent div which is "flip" and the card matching is happening to the child div which is "block" by using the data-attribute. But after selecting two divs, if they are not equal then the flipping is not happening to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery *each()* function will perform function on each item of an array.

https://api.jquery.com/JQuery.each/

```js
//shuffle position of cards

$.fn.shuffleChildren = function () {
  $.each(this.get(), function (index, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var $find = $el.children();

    $find.sort(function () {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });

    $el.empty();
    $find.appendTo($el);
  });
};

$(".parent1").shuffleChildren();
$(".parent2").shuffleChildren();

var counter = 3;
var attempt = document.getElementById("count");
attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";


var inner = $(".inner");

function hideCards() {
  inner.addClass("isFlipped");
  inner.click(function () {
    var elem = $(this); //returns inner div
    elem.toggleClass("isFlipped");
    var child = elem.find(".front").children(); //returns block class
    //var first = child.attr("data-type"); //returns data-type of the block class
    if (child.hasClass("matched")) {
      return;
    }

    child.toggleClass("selected");
    child.siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");

    var selected = $("[data-type].selected");
    if (selected.length === 2) {
      var type1 = selected.eq(0).data("type");
      var type2 = selected.eq(1).data("type");
      var isMatch = type1 === type2;
      if (isMatch) {
        selected.removeClass("selected").toggleClass("matched", isMatch, 2000);
        attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(() => { // Delay hiding of cards for 2 seconds
            // flip each selected card
            $.each(selected,(idx,card) => {
              $(card).parents('.inner').addClass('isFlipped');
            });
          },2000);
        selected.removeClass("selected");
      /*
        var inr = selected.parent().parent();
        console.log(inr);
        inr.map(function(element) {
          $(element).addClass("isFlipped");
        });
      */

        counter -= 1;
        if (counter == 0) {
          attempt.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!!";
        }
        else {
          attempt.innerHTML = "You've " + counter + " lives";
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

setTimeout(hideCards, 5000);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,400i,700");

.parent1,
.parent2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;  
  display: flex;
}

.parent1 div,
.parent2 div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.block1,
.block2 {
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
}

[data-type].selected,
[data-type].selected:hover {
  border: 3px solid white;
}

[data-type].matched {
  display: none;
}

[data-type]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

[data-type="c1"] {
  background-color: #F44336;
}

[data-type="c2"] {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

[data-type="c3"] {
  background-color: #8E24AA;
}

[data-type="c4"] {
  background-color: #5E35B1;
}

[data-type="c5"] {
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}

[data-type="c6"] {
  background-color: #00796B;
}

[data-type="c7"] {
  background-color: #AFB42B;
}

[data-type="c8"] {
  background-color: #FF8F00;
}

.gameover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: coral;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.buttons {
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.gameover h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* FLIP CARD */

.flip {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* .flip:hover .inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
} */

.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background-color: pink;
}

.back {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.inner.isFlipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameover">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>GAME OVER!!</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="">Retry</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="parent1">
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c1">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c8">8</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c7">7</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c6">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c5">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c4">4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c3">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block1" data-type="c2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent2">
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c1">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c8">8</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c7">7</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c6">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c5">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c4">4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c3">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="block2" data-type="c2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="count"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used forEach but it didn't work before. But i understood your solution. But could you please tell me what is the purpose of idx here?

Comment: Idx is for the index parameter which is the first parameter of the callback for each and it isn't used for this implementation.